# Mass update mysql table

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a list of 1933 user names that have to be set to deleted in a mysql table (change the deleted field from 0 to 1). I'm pasting  a comma delimited list (username, realname) in a list box and using a foreach statement to send  each username, realname group to an update command in a static class. When I run it, I don't get any errors but none of the users rows are updated.  I'm doing something wrong but I'm not sure what the issue is. Please review my code below and let me know if you find something wrong that I'm not seeing.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        try
        {
            if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (string s in listBox1.Items)
                {
                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                    string[] sname = s.Split(',');
                    Data.RemoveUser(sname[0].ToString(), sname[1].ToString());
                    i++;
                    label3.Text = i.ToString();
                }
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("No user names found. Please paste a list of names to be deleted.");
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
            MessageBox.Show(i.ToString() + " users set to deleted.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }


public static void RemoveUser(string UserName, string FullName)
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constr);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            string qry = "Update host_user set deleted = 1 where username = @username and name = @fname";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(qry, conn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", UserName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", FullName);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                    

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            if (conn != null) conn.Close();
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: set a break point on cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() and when it breaks on it, in the immediate window type "?cmd.CommandText"   Is it a valid mysql statement?

Comment: You don't need to escape "username" and/or "name" do you...are they reserved words?

Comment: And I would prefer this parameter add construct:  `cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserName;`

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing:

```
string[] sname = s.Split(',');
```

Do you end up with spaces on either side of you first name and last name? If your input was like:

"John, Doe"

You would end up search on "John" & " Doe".

If this is the case, call .Trim() on those strings before passing passing them into RemoveUser().

Comment: Or split on `", "` which would avoid errors in case the names had actual whitespace in the database.